# Javascript- callback function for start, stop, reset buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

My code currently fades in and out, one word at a time, any text that I add to the h1 tag, it displays within a small box. I have added 3 buttons that currently have no script attached in order to function.

What I want to happen is when someone visits my webpage, they can press Start and the text will fade in and out in the aforementioned box. I would also like visitors to be able to stop and reset the text that I have written in the h1 tag. All the visitor should see is the 3 buttons and the box upon visiting my site. Once they click start the text will fade in and out, centered within the box.

In summary I need the 3 buttons within the HTML to function with the current script. I would be thankful for any help.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="box">
    <div id="title"><span id="name">Title</span> 
    </div>
    <div id="message"/>
    <div id="greeting"/>
        <input type="button" value="Start" id="start" />
        <input type="button" value="Stop" id="stop"/>
        <input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset" />
         <h1><center>This is a test. This is only a test.</center></h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    border:1px solid #E38E34;
    background-color: #FFE7BF;
    height:150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#title {
    margin:5px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #E38E34;
    color:#C46908;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#message {
    margin:5px;
}
center {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

**Script**

```
var h1 = $('div#greeting h1');

h1.hide().contents().each(function () {
    var words;
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        words = '<span> ' + this.data.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
        $(this).replaceWith(words);
    } else if (this.nodeType === 1) {
        this.innerHTML = '<span> ' + this.innerHTML.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
    }
});

h1.find('span').hide().each(function () {
    if (!$.trim(this.innerHTML)) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});

h1.show().find('span').each(function (i) {
    $(this).delay(600 * i).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j42fL/

Comment: Whoa, haven't seen <center> in years.

Comment: You like that. That's old school. I'm calling back memories of the one class I ever took on computer programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j42fL/3/

```
var h1 = $('div#greeting h1');

$.setAnim = function(h1) {
    h1.hide().html('<center>This is a test. This is only a test.</center>').contents().each(function () {
        var words;
        if (this.nodeType === 3) {
            words = '<span> ' + this.data.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
            $(this).replaceWith(words);
        } else if (this.nodeType === 1) {
            this.innerHTML = '<span> ' + this.innerHTML.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
        }
    });
}

$.startAnim = function(h1) {
    h1.find('span').hide().each(function () {
        if (!$.trim(this.innerHTML)) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    h1.show().find('span').each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay(600 * i).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200);
    });
}

$.stopAnim = function(h1) {
    h1.find('span').stop(true, true);
}

$.resetAnim = function(h1) {
    $.stopAnim(h1);
    $.setAnim(h1);
}

$.setAnim(h1);

$('#start').click(function(){ $.startAnim(h1); });
$('#stop').click(function(){ $.stopAnim(h1); });
$('#reset').click(function(){ $.resetAnim(h1); });
```